# Kotlin ConflatedBroadcastChannel.offer() doesn't work?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel, coroutinescope

I am sending a value via `MyRepository.myConflatedChannel.offer(myvalue)`.

I then expect to receive it in `collect { }` or `onEach { }` blocks in my ViewModel.  However, neither function is invoked.  It is as if nothing is passed down the ConflatedBroadcastChannel.

Has anybody seen a similar problem?

Comment: Did you got a ReceiveChannel by `openSubscription` call or a `consume` call?

Comment: Do you transform this channel into a flow? I think `collect` works for flows only

Comment: Have you tried using `Poll()` it's the synchronous counterpart to `Offer()`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu `flow.collect` is the same as `consume`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it is a [method](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/poll.html) on a ReceiveChannel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you properly work with receiving values.

If you use the ConflatedBroadcastChannel, you can use either [OpenSubscription](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-conflated-broadcast-channel/open-subscription.html) to get a [ReceiveChannel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/index.html) or you can represent it as flow (with [asFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/as-flow.html)).

Note that `consume` and `consumeEach` are terminal, they perform an action and then cancel the channel after the execution of the block. See [this](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/consume-each.html).

First case:

```
val receivingChannel = MyRepository.myConflatedChannel.openSubscription()
// then you can consume values using for example a for loop, e.g.:

launch {
    for (value in receivingChannel) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Second case:

```
val receivingFlow = MyRepository.myConflatedChannel.asFlow()

launch {
    receivingFlow.collect {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I just use regular `BroadcastChannel`?